# Firebase automatic login failes on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I'm developing an application using flutter. I'm facing an error when user logs in the application on an android device, terminates the app and opens the app again,  the _firebaseAuth.currentUser returns the current user details, but when the same is done on iOS, it returns null. Can anyone suggest why this happens. The plugin version is firebase_auth 0.18.0+1. Sharing the code for checking the
`

```
bool isSignedIn() {
    try {
      final currentUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      return currentUser != null;
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

`
i've used bloc like this

`

```
runApp(BlocProvider(
    create: (_) => AuthBloc(userRepository: _userRepository)..add(AppStarted()),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
```

`

`

```
Stream<AuthState> _mapAppStarted() async* {
    try {
      final isSignedIn = _userRepository.isSignedIn();
      if (isSignedIn) {
        final user = await _userRepository.getUser();
        if (user == null) {
          await _userRepository.signOut();
          yield Unauthenticated();
        } else {
          List<FollowedFollowingModel> followedFollowingList =
              await getFollowingList(user);
          yield Authenticated(user, followedFollowingList);
        }
      } else {
        yield Unauthenticated();
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield Unauthenticated();
    }
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In the main.dart file inside a `Material widget` you can use it like following:

```
home: FutureBuilder<FirebaseApp>(
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseApp> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
                  ? GettingStarted() 
                  : Dashboard();
            }

            /// other way there is no user logged.
            return Scaffold();
          }),
```

Comment: try a async function then

Comment: the problem is that in the latest auth plugin, the current user can be acquired without using async/await now.

Comment: i've updated the question. Added how i implemented it